# Testing element size change

Tags: swift, nspredicate, xctest

I created my own style for a disclosure group, and I'd like to write a test that verifies whether tapping on its elements expands the group. Initially, I wrote a test to check if tapping toggles the visibility of the contents, but the corresponding element is always present in the object tree, so this approach didn't work. Therefore, I have decided to write a test that checks the change in height of the element when it is tapped:

```swift
func testItemExpansion() {
    let item = app.groups.element
    let oldHeight = item.frame.height
    let heightIncrease = expectation(
        for: NSPredicate(format: "frame.height > \(oldHeight)",
        evaluatedWith: item
    )
    item.tap()
    wait(for: [heightIncrease], timeout: 5) // Always times out :(
}
```

The test above always times out. What's wrong with it? Is there a better approach to test this?

Comment: A string literal (what String Interpolation actually represents) in a predicate expression must be quoted. Why don't you use the `format` pattern?

Comment: I'm getting `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4042800000000000)` when I change the predicate to `"frame.height > %@", oldHeight`. But the test passes if I change it to e.g. `isHittable == true`.

Comment: The correct [format specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for double scalar values is `%f`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the runtime error, but the test still times out. Here's the logs:
`Checking \`Expect predicate \`frame.height > 37\` for object Group at {{96.0, 520.0}, {645.0, 37.0}}\`. Find the Group at {{96.0, 520.0}, {645.0, 37.0}}. Checking \`Expect predicate \`frame.height > 37\` for object Group at {{96.0, 520.0}, {645.0, 37.0}}\` ...`

Comment: I changed my predicate to `NSPredicate { group, _ in ... oldHeight < group.frame.height }`, and the test passed. But I still would like to know what's wrong with my original predicate.